# Rails field not displayed in view

Tags: ruby-on-rails, view

I have the following code in my `show` view.

```
<p>
  <strong>Average difference:</strong>
  <%= @prediction.average_difference %>
</p>
```

However, the field's value is not printed.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

Fire up rails console to check @prediction.average_difference if it shows up a value their in console it must show the same in the view as well.

Answer (score 1):

Probably `@average_difference` attribute of `@prediction` is `nil`. In order to confirm that, you may write

`<%= @prediction.average_difference || 'test_average_difference' %>`

which should display `test_average_difference`.